# Can't sign cloudfront URLs using boto

Tags: python, boto, amazon-cloudfront

I've written the following code to sign URLS using boto, however, I'm unable to access the signed URLS. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
con = cloudfront.CloudFrontConnection(
    settings.AWS_USER_DETAILS.access_key_id,
    settings.AWS_USER_DETAILS.secret_key_id,
)

identities = con.get_all_origin_access_identity()

if len(identities) < 1:
    oai = con.create_origin_access_identity(
        'cv-oai',
        'OAI signing iOS video requests'
    )
else:
    oai = con.get_all_origin_access_identity()[0]

distro_summary = con.get_all_distributions()[0]
distro_info = con.get_distribution_info(distro_summary.id)

bucket = boto.connect_s3(
    settings.AWS_USER_DETAILS.access_key_id,
    settings.AWS_USER_DETAILS.secret_key_id,
    host='s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'
).get_bucket(u'cv-video')

key_str = video.video_url.split('/')[-1]
key = bucket.get_key(key_str)

key.add_user_grant("READ", oai.s3_user_id)

distro = distro_summary.get_distribution()

# For local testing
if ip_addr == '127.0.0.1':
    ip_addr = None

private_key_string = open(settings.CF_PRIV_KEY_LOC).read()
print private_key_string

signed_url = distro.create_signed_url(
    "https://%s/%s" % (distro_info.domain_name, key_str),
    'APKAI3I3QZ7I73OIQIXA',
    expire_time=int(time.time()) + video.video_length + 5 * 60,
    #valid_after_time=None,
    #ip_address=ip_addr,
    #policy_url=None,
    private_key_string=private_key_string
)
```

**Error:**

**Update:** This is the error received when visiting the URLs generated by the above code. I am unable to find documentation of the CloudFront errors to determine why this might be happening.

```
<Error>
<Code>InvalidKey</Code>
<Message>Unknown Key</Message>
</Error>
```

**Example URL:**

https://d1xvt07pr26drp.cloudfront.net/2iwjz3wn9atqlfw4.mov?Expires=1388705061&Signature=auPWW-X1LzZJkPxJ5YPCqQMatchbAb3BxCWTG5oMY78G6LrH0sZiQL6EKdCX-l3Fi9E475b11uFL~HnxfBUY9QqQH86478QU5BnpmR-U7uEikRs7kTDWOVj4Riv3PHUmjmzlBW8xU7-n9C0m2UZSXedPsYYFdPoWHH0VLlyKk2TzgYydLqu~jtq0iNdmz-C9TOgUCaICiMYi082AVc7bt6xTfVszA9BeAD4KLKnr42raFDLojbA78Q-7bLNA2CiStdT-8BblQOQ5IXUCxYdkw7ak0vp77vER1pCG9cEBkCHD~9dZccyQEGJApO~ax4D5wDtCpeQj3l0pW6kYNUlP8Q__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAI3I3QZ7I73OIQIXA

**The key pair is definitely active:**

[image: Key Pair is active]

**There is only one Origin Access Identity and one distribution:**

```
[<boto.cloudfront.identity.OriginAccessIdentitySummary object at 0x10f356110>]
[<boto.cloudfront.distribution.DistributionSummary object at 0x10f356090>]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue.

I wondered if couldfront and s3 had not yet been connected logically to the "origin access identity."  This is the identity that cloudfront uses to pull content from S3, verifying signatures with the private key pair you specified.

Sure enough, that was the problem.  Disable public access to the underlying S3 bucket, then tell AWS to use the appropriate identity, then try your code again.

Here's how from the Web:

From the CloudFront dashboard (https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/home), click on "Distribution" on the left to see all your distros.  Select the one you want, clicking the [i] icon for more information.  From there, click on the [Origins] tab and select the radio button next to your bucket.  Click it, and an Edit button will appear.  Click Edit.  Choose "Restrict Bucket Access" in the new panel that appears.  The site will prompt you for which access identity to do.  Choose the identity you created.  Click "Yes, Edit" to save your changes.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will look into this ASAP and hopefully award you the bounty when this gets it working.

Comment: Let me know when you get it working!  I'm in the midst of hacking around with cloudfront, too, now playing with CNAMEs for more "fun."

Comment: When I used a CNAME host, I needed one more step.  After you've done the above, go into the S3 bucket.  Click on "Permissions." Here you'll see your account, as well as "Everyone."  Delete "Everyone".  Then click "Add Permissions."  A new dropdown list will pop up.  Here, select the Cloudfront Access Identity, then click "List" and "View".  This tells S3 that you want cloudfront to view and list the items in your bucket, via a special user that cloudfront creates.

Comment: @ScottPenberthy I do not see any 'Cloudfront Access Identity' in a dropdown. How can I get it appear in the dropdown?

Comment: @Anthony Kong you can create a new one if there is none in the list.